I am searching for a story I partially recall but can't identify
The story I am looking for was probably published around the 1960s. I think it was a novel, but it might have been shorter. I believe the author was well-known. The plot of the story is that society is disintegrating and in desperation, the president agrees to a scheme to send a small crew of carefully selected individuals to a distant planet that has just been discovered. In truth, the planet doesn't exist. The real purpose of the voyage is to create an environment that may lead to the crew members achieving new insights that can save civilisation on earth. During the voyage, the crew members do acquire unusual abilities. Eventually they work out that they have been duped and they do something that destroys all atomic weapons on earth. Ultimately they reach their destination and create the planet they were supposed to travel to. On earth, civilisation has pretty much crumbled and there is a new president who is something of a rogue. The voyagers send a message by morse code using laser light that they are returning to earth and want to see the man who was responsible for organising their voyage. The president thinks he can use him to gain some advantage, but the man then dies.
This is how I think I remember the story. I would really like to know the title of it and the author.

The Gold at Starbows End

Or there is version adapted into a novel called Starburst. both have been asked about many times already. In fact it was asked about only a couple of weeks ago. From your description I think the novel version is the one you read.

Almost certainly one of these. "The Gold at Starbows End" was a short story that was later expanded into a novel called "Starburst"

It sounds very much like the SyFy series Ascension.

Tim, please let us know if it is Starburst so we can mark this as a duplicate. Thanks :-)
